# How to join two objects and all space between them in Blender?

Tags: modeling

What modifier or command can let me join the two objects at the top, including any space between them, to become the object at the bottom?  Like a boolean union + join closest vertices command? Thanks

[image]

Comment: There's not one command, you need to join the 2 objects and fill the gap with a face

Comment: How could you do that in nodes or in a script though? Your way sounds too manual